# How to keep the state updated using useeffect

Tags: reactjs, loops, react-hooks

Im working on a feature in a administrative panel which display the alerts inside of the applicacion.
I have 3 methods:

1. GET => get the data from the DB
2. UPDATE => update a alert depending of the ID
3. DELETE => delete the alert depending of the ID

I wanted to use a useeffect and specifying that when to UPDATE or DELETE method is execute it. Triggers the GET method and set a new state with the updated data.

```
// NEW FEAUTURE: ALERTS
  const AlertList= () => {
    const [alerts, setAlerts] = useState([])

    const getAlerts = async () => {
      const data = await getAlertService()
      setAlerts(data)
    }

    const updateAlerts = async (updatedAlert) => {
      await updateAlertService(updatedAlert)
    }

    async function deleteAlert(alertID) {
      await deleteAlertService({ id: alertID})
    }

    // SET THE STATE
    useEffect(() => {
      getAlertas()
    }, [])

    // WHEN THE UPDATE OR DELETE METHOD IS EXECUTE IT.RUN THE GETALERTS TO UPDATE THE STATE
    useEffect(() => {
      getAlertas()
    }, [updateAlerts, deleteAlert])

    return (
      <div className="container container--flex--centered">
        <div className="dashboard--title--container">
          <h1 className="title">Alertas</h1>
        </div>
          <FiltroAlertas setAlertas={setAlertas}/>
          <WidgetAlertas alertas={alertas} eliminarAlerta={eliminarAlerta} actualizarAlerta={updateAlerta}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

The problem is that create a infinite loop. I dont know why

I wanted to add the useeffect to just listen. When the update or delete method is execute it. Run the function getAlerts to bringing the updated data and set the new state.

Comment: Your dependencies are wrong... And you should just remove the dependency array when you aren't using it. Perhaps create a variable to trigger those updates... Or just call it directly... (In other words call the getAlertas function immediately after (and inside) the updateAlerts and deleteAlert functions if you want it to be called after.

Answer (score 0):

The infinite loop is because of this dependency array:

```
[updateAlerts, deleteAlert]
```

Those are *functions*, not *data*.  And those functions are re-declared and re-created on every render.  So this effect is triggered on every render.  And this effect updates state, which triggers a re-render.  Which triggers this effect.  Which updates state.  Etc.  Etc.

(Or at least, that *appears* to be what's happening.  We don't know what `getAlertas()` does, since it's not shown here.)

What do `updateAlertService` and `deleteAlertService` do?  If they modify state of any kind, that *state* would likely be the dependency for this effect.  Though if that state *is* `alerts` then you shouldn't need to re-fetch it after updating it.  If those operations are invoking server-side changes, once that is complete you can just update client-side state accordingly.

Or, if you want to ensure the data is synchronized with other potential server-side changes, you'd re-invoke `getAlerts` (or `getAlertas`?) after performing those operations.  *Not* as a dependency of those operations.

For example, your `updateAlertService` function may internally call `getAlerts` (or `getAlertas`?) after it has completed whatever it is updating.

Answer (score 0):

A function is still a variable. Adding a local function as a dependency of `useEffect` will run that effect every time your component renders. Given that the body of the effect also changes state, you get the infinite re-render.

`useEffect` isn't helpful here, you can call `getAlerts` from `updateAlerts` and `deleteAlert`

```
 const AlertList= () => {
    const [alerts, setAlerts] = useState([])

    const getAlerts = async () => {
      const data = await getAlertService()
      setAlerts(data)
    }

    const updateAlerta = async (updatedAlert) => {
      await updateAlertService(updatedAlert)
      getAlerts();
    }

    async function eliminarAlerta(alertID) {
      await deleteAlertService({ id: alertID})
      getAlerts();
    }

    // SET THE STATE
    useEffect(() => {
      getAlerts()
    }, [])

    return (
      <div className="container container--flex--centered">
        <div className="dashboard--title--container">
          <h1 className="title">Alertas</h1>
        </div>
          <FiltroAlertas setAlertas={setAlertas}/>
          <WidgetAlertas alertas={alertas} eliminarAlerta={eliminarAlerta} actualizarAlerta={updateAlerta}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
```